# com.azure.core.exception.HttpResponseException: Deserialization Failed

Tags: azure-media-services

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-java/tree/main/VideoEncoding/EncodingWithMESCustomPreset

I tried to execute with code on Github address.
Changed build method from Maven to Gradle.
I built it with Gradle and ran it. When executed, the error occurs, such as the image.
Why is there an error when I didn't fix the code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La03E.png)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your query?

Comment: Hello. I added an explanation as you responded.

@SnehaAgrawal-MSFT